# Find all subarray with sum equal to number?

Tags: javascript

Could you please tell me how to find all subarray with sum equal to number
Example

```
arr[] = [2, 4, 45, 6, 0, 19]
   x  =  51
Output: [2,4,45]
```

Or

```
arr[] = [1, 11, 100, 1, 0, 200, 3, 2, 1, 280]
    x = 280
Output: [280]
```

I tried like that but not getting correct output

```js
function getSubArray(arr, num) {
  var sum = 0,
    blank = [];
  var bigArr = []
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum = arr[i];
    if (blank.length === 0) {
      blank.push(arr[i]);
    }
    for (var j = 1; i < arr.length; j++) {
      sum += arr[j];
      if (sum < num) {
        blank.push(arr[j])
      } else if (sum > num) {
        sum = 0;
        blank = [];
        break;
      } else {
        blank.push(arr[j])
        bigArr.push(blank);
        sum = 0;
        blank = [];
      }
    }
  }

  return bigArr
}

console.log(getSubArray([1, 3, 6, 11, 1, 5, 4], 4));
```

for this expected output is

```
console.log(getSubArray([1, 3, 6, 11, 1, 5,4],4));

output: [1,3]
     [4]
```

**expected output
[[1,3], [4]] is my expected output**

Comment: Not able to make out anything from the question

Comment: @brk as mentioned I am not getting subarray using my function

Comment: @brk given an array of numbers and a target number, find the smallest possible section of the array that when summed equals the target number. I *think*, I don't know if it's supposed to be a subarray (so, preserving order of the elements) or any valid combination of the array elements.

Comment: @user944513 What happens when the numbers cannot add up to that number

Comment: @nickzoum show not found .it is number array, not objects

Comment: do you need only one smallest result or all smallest result or simply all results with all permutations of matching items?

Comment: If the point is to find the smallest subarray, then why do you need to return `[4]` and `[1,3]` it should only be `[4]`. Else you should return all combinations possible.

Comment: do you have negative values as well?

Comment: Do you mean sub-array or sub-sequence? Because sub-array is contiguous, but sub-sequence isn't

Comment: it gives all combinations

Comment: subarray with contigous

Comment: @user944513 then why have [3, 1] in your expected output?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes negative value...it gives all cobination of subarray which should be contigous

Comment: [[1,3],[4]] is my expected output

Comment: sorry I edit my question and comment [3,1] I am not expecting

Comment: Another clarifiaction needed - why expect `[1, 3]`? You already have `[4]` which is the smallest that sums to `4`, so `[1, 3]` would be the *second* smallest.

Comment: yup can i get all subarray ..after that to get smallest subarray from the array list

Comment: first I will try to get all subarray then afer from that list will try to find smallest subaaray

Comment: see update of my question .I am trying to find all subarray  which have sum to a given number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could iterate the array and take either the next element or if no element is taken before omit this element.

```js
function getSubset(array, sum) {
    function iter(temp, delta, index) {
        if (!delta) result.push(temp);
        if (index >= array.length) return;
        iter(temp.concat(array[index]), delta - array[index], index + 1);
        if (!temp.length) iter(temp, delta, index + 1);
    }

    var result = [];
    iter([], sum, 0);
    return result;
}

console.log(getSubset([2, 4, 45, 6, 0, 19], 51));                   // [2, 4, 45], [45, 6], [45, 6, 0]
console.log(getSubset([1, 11, 100, 1, 0, 200, 3, 2, 1, 280], 280)); // [280]
console.log(getSubset([1, 3, 6, 11, 1, 5, 4], 4));                  // [1, 3], [4]
```

Comment: If you try `console.log(getSubset([2, 4, 50, 45, 5,1, 0, 19,1], 51));` you get `[45,5,1]`, instead of `[50, 1]`

Comment: just as an improvement you could first filter the array and remove any numbers above our target sum.

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov, ithink the returned elements should have a continuous index ...maybe not?

Comment: @iacobalin, this approach does not work with negative values, because you need greater numbers as the target sum.

Comment: It does not find all possible "subarrays"

Comment: @Marcus, if finds only numbers who are connected.

Comment: The first test case miss `[45, 6, 0]`

Comment: For getSubset([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 10) it only find one subarray

Comment: @Marcus, yes. that is right, as i understand the question, all values should be adjacent to each other.

Comment: @NinaScholz You may be right on this one as the guy asked about sub-arrays while I thought about sub-sets

Answer (score 2):

This might not be exactly what's needed - might require tweaking as the logic may be flawed here.

I have commented the code for clarification.

```js
var arr = [1, 3, 6, 11, 1, 5,4]; //  Define array

var target = 31; //  Define target

//  filter the numbers higher than target and sort rest ascending
var withinRange = arr.filter(x => x <= target).sort((a, b) => a - b);
                      
if(arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b) < target) //  Check if we have enough numbers to make up that number
  throw "The max you can get out of your selection is: " + arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
                      
//  grab the highest number as a starting point and remove it from our array of numbers
var numbers = [withinRange.pop()];

var toFind = target - getSum(); //  get remainder to find

for(var i = withinRange.length - 1; i > -1; i--) //  iterate from the top
{

  if(toFind == withinRange[i]){ //  check if number is exactly what we need
    numbers.push(withinRange[i]);
    break;
  }else if(withinRange[i] <= toFind){ //  if number is smaller than what we look for
    numbers.push(withinRange[i]);
    toFind -= withinRange[i];
  }

}

function getSum(){ //  sum up our found numbers
  if(numbers.length == 0) return 0;
  return numbers.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
}

console.log([numbers, [target]]); //  print numbers as desired output
console.log(target, getSum()) //  print the target and our numbers
```

Comment: Very clear and well working solution.Might be a bit slow because of all the operations.

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov Indeed, it might be slow, but it can be optimised. Things such as reduce can be called once for example.

Answer (score 2):

---

```
function combinations(array) {
    return new Array(1 << array.length).fill().map(
        (e1,i) => array.filter((e2, j) => i & 1 << j));
}
```

---

```
function add(acc,a) {
  return acc + a 
}
```

---

```
combinations([2, 4, 45, 6, 0, 19]).filter( subarray => subarray.reduce(add, 0)  == 51 )
```

---

**output**

```
[[2,4,45],[45,6],[2,4,45,0],[45,6,0]]
```

---

```
combinations([1, 11, 100, 1, 0, 200, 3, 2, 1, 280]).filter( subarray => subarray.reduce(add, 0)  == 280 )
```

---

**output**

```
[[280],[0,280]]
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I just wonder why `1 << i` and not  `2 ** i`, if I understand it right?

Answer (score 1):

This will try every possible permutation of the array (will stop further permutations once limit is reached)

```js
function test(arr, num) {
  // sorting will improve time as larger values will be eliminated first
  arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
  });
  var allLists = [];
  var start = Date.now();
  helper(0, 0, []);
  console.log("Ms elapesed: " + (Date.now() - start));
  return allLists || "Not found";

  function helper(start, total, list) {
    var result = [];
    // Using for loop is faster because you can start from desired index without using filter, slice, splice ...
    for (var index = start; index < arr.length; index++) {
      var item = arr[index];
      // If the total is too large the path can be skipped alltogether
      if (total + item <= num) {
        // Check lists if number was not included
        var test = helper(index + 1, total, list.concat(result)); // remove for efficiency
        total += item;
        result.push(item);
        //if (total === num) index = arr.length; add for efficiency
      }
    }
    if (total === num) allLists.push(list.concat(result));
  }
}



console.log(test([2, 4, 45, 6, 0, 19], 51)); // [2,4,45] [2,4,45,0] [6,45] [6,45,0]
console.log(test([1, 11, 100, 1, 0, 200, 3, 2, 1, 280], 280)); // [280] [280,0]
```

If you want to make it more efficient and just return one of the resulted array just comment out the recursive call. You can also un-comment the line that exits the loop once the limit has been reached (will skip 0s).

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: getMin is not defined

Comment: @Marcus Sorry i renamed it to `helper` and didnt change all the references

Comment: @Marcus this solution will return every possible subarray

Answer (score 1):

It will give all the available case. And I use the test case of @Nina Scholz

```js
const sum = arr => arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b)

function cal(arr, x) {
  const rs = []
  for (let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    const tmp = []
    for (let j=i; j<arr.length; j++ ) {
      tmp.push(arr[j])
      if(sum(tmp) === x) rs.push([...tmp])
    }
  }
  return rs
}


console.log(cal([1, 11, 100, 1, 0, 200, 3, 2, 1, 280], 280)) // -> [280]
console.log(cal([2, 4, 45, 6, 0, 19], 51)); // -> [2, 4, 45] [45, 6] [45, 6, 0]
console.log(cal([1, 3, 6, 11, 1, 5, 4], 4)); // -> [1,3] [4]
```

Comment: what about `[2,4,45,0]` ?

Comment: @nickzoum It isn't contiguous, is it?

Comment: sorry, i completely missed that part

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about finding all subsets (rather than subarrays) with the given cross sum it is also known as the perfect sum problem.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perfect-sum-problem-print-subsets-given-sum/

```
// A recursive function to print all subsets with the 
// help of dp[][]. Vector p[] stores current subset. 
function printSubsetsRec(arr, i, sum, p) 
{ 
    // If we reached end and sum is non-zero. We print 
    // p[] only if arr[0] is equal to sun OR dp[0][sum] 
    // is true. 
    if (i == 0 && sum != 0 && dp[0][sum]) 
    { 
        p.push(arr[i]); 
        console.log(p); 
        return; 
    } 

    // If sum becomes 0 
    if (i == 0 && sum == 0) 
    { 
        console.log(p); 
        return; 
    } 

    // If given sum can be achieved after ignoring 
    // current element. 
    if (dp[i-1][sum]) 
    { 
        // Create a new vector to store path 
        var b = p.slice(0); 
        printSubsetsRec(arr, i-1, sum, b); 
    } 

    // If given sum can be achieved after considering 
    // current element. 
    if (sum >= arr[i] && dp[i-1][sum-arr[i]]) 
    { 
        p.push(arr[i]); 
        printSubsetsRec(arr, i-1, sum-arr[i], p); 
    } 
} 

// Prints all subsets of arr[0..n-1] with sum 0. 
function printAllSubsets(arr, sum) 
{ 
    var n = arr.length
    if (n == 0 || sum < 0) 
       return; 

    // Sum 0 can always be achieved with 0 elements 
    dp = []; 
    for (var i=0; i<n; ++i) 
    { 
        dp[i] = []
        dp[i][0] = true; 
    } 

    // Sum arr[0] can be achieved with single element 
    if (arr[0] <= sum) 
       dp[0][arr[0]] = true; 

    // Fill rest of the entries in dp[][] 
    for (var i = 1; i < n; ++i) 
        for (var j = 0; j < sum + 1; ++j) 
            dp[i][j] = (arr[i] <= j) ? dp[i-1][j] || 
                                       dp[i-1][j-arr[i]] 
                                     : dp[i - 1][j]; 
    if (dp[n-1][sum] == false) 
    { 
        console.log("There are no subsets with sum %d\n", sum); 
        return; 
    } 

    // Now recursively traverse dp[][] to find all 
    // paths from dp[n-1][sum] 
    var p = []; 
    printSubsetsRec(arr, n-1, sum, p); 
} 

printAllSubsets([1,2,3,4,5], 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
'use strict';

function print(arr[], i, j) {
   let k = 0;
   for (k = i; k <= j; k += 1) {
     console.log(arr[k]);
   }
}

function findSubArrays(arr[], sum) {
  let n = arr.length;
  let i;
  let j;
  let sum_so_far;

  for (i = 0; i<n; i+= 1) {
    sum_so_far = 0;
    for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
      sum_so_far += arr[j];

      if (sum_so_far === sum) {
         print(arr, i, j);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first loop depending on the size of expected arrays.

After that loop for looking for first part of the array which should be filled with positions that will match the desired number.

For example for x= 4  having arr=[5,4,32,8,2,1,2,2,3,4,4]
It would first take the 4's. Output will start on [ [4], [4], [4], .....  ] for positions 1,9,10 (respectively)

Then go for the arrays resulting sum of 2 elements [ ... [2,2], [2,2],[2,2], [1,3] ...] ( positions 4+6, position 4+7 position6+7 and position 5+8)
You would probably want to use another function to sum and check at this point.

Now will do the same for sum of 3 elements (if any) and so on, having max loop set at number of original array (the resulting number could be the sum of all the elements in the array).

The resulting example would be [ [4], [4], [4], [2,2], [2,2],[2,2], [1,3]]

Answer (score 0):

If the elements would be strictly positive, one could collect such subsequences in a single pass, progressing in a worm/caterpillar-like way: stretching its front in order to grow the sum (when it is bellow the target) and contracting its back in order to lower the sum:

```js
function worm(arr,target){
  var ret=[];
  var head=0;
  var tail=0;
  var sum=0;
  while(head<arr.length){
    while(sum<=target && head<arr.length){
      sum+=arr[head++];
      if(sum===target)
        ret.push(arr.slice(tail,head));
    }
    while(sum>=target && tail<head){
      sum-=arr[tail++];
      if(sum===target)
        ret.push(arr.slice(tail,head));
    }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(arr)+": "+JSON.stringify(ret);
}

console.log(worm([2, 4, 45, 6, 19], 51));
console.log(worm([1, 11, 100, 1, 200, 3, 2, 1, 280], 280));
console.log(worm([1, 3, 6, 11, 1, 5, 4], 4));

console.log("But it only occasionally finds 0+... / ...+0 sums:");
console.log(worm([2, 4, 45, 6, 0, 19], 51));
console.log(worm([2, 4, 0, 45, 0, 6, 0, 19], 51));
console.log(worm([0, 2, 4, 0, 45, 0, 6, 0, 19], 51));
```

One way to deal with the problem related to bounding zeroes is to throw such sequences away. This snippet keeps `tail` and `head(-1)` on non-zero elements:

```js
function worm(arr,target){
  var ret=[];
  var head=0;
  while(head<arr.length && arr[head]===0)head++;
  var tail=head;
  var sum=0;
  while(head<arr.length){
    while(sum<=target && head<arr.length){
      while(head<arr.length && arr[head]===0)head++;
      sum+=arr[head++];
      if(sum===target)
        ret.push(arr.slice(tail,head));
    }
    while(sum>=target && tail<head){
      sum-=arr[tail++];
      while(tail<head && arr[tail]===0)tail++;
      if(sum===target)
        ret.push(arr.slice(tail,head));
    }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(arr)+": "+JSON.stringify(ret);
}

console.log(worm([2, 4, 45, 6, 19], 51));
console.log(worm([1, 11, 100, 1, 200, 3, 2, 1, 280], 280));
console.log(worm([1, 3, 6, 11, 1, 5, 4], 4));
console.log(worm([2, 4, 45, 6, 0, 19], 51));
console.log(worm([2, 4, 0, 45, 0, 6, 0, 19], 51));
console.log(worm([0, 2, 4, 0, 45, 0, 6, 0, 19], 51));
console.log(worm([0, 2, 4, 0, 45, 0, 6, 0, 19, 26], 51));
console.log(worm([0, 2, 4, 0, 45, 0, 6, 0, 19, 26, 0], 51));
console.log(worm([1,8,2], 10));
console.log(worm([0,1,0,8,2,0], 10));
console.log(worm([0,8,2,8,0], 10));
console.log(worm([0,8,0,2,0,8,0], 10));
```

And the code loses all of its remaining beauty if someone actually needs those `0+...` / `...+0` sequences, as they have to be generated in a post-processing step:

```js
function worm(arr,target){
  var pairs=[];
  var head=0;
  while(head<arr.length && arr[head]===0)head++;
  var tail=head;
  var sum=0;
  while(head<arr.length){
    while(sum<=target && head<arr.length){
      while(head<arr.length && arr[head]===0)head++;
      sum+=arr[head++];
      if(sum===target)
        pairs.push([tail,head]);
    }
    while(sum>=target && tail<head){
      sum-=arr[tail++];
      while(tail<head && arr[tail]===0)tail++;
      if(sum===target)
        pairs.push([tail,head]);
    }
  }
  var ret=[];
  for([tail,head] of pairs){
    (function pre(tail,head){
      ret.push(arr.slice(tail,head));
      if(tail>0 && arr[tail-1]===0)
        pre(tail-1,head);
      (function post(tail,head){
        if(head<arr.length && arr[head]===0){
          ret.push(arr.slice(tail,head+1));
          post(tail,head+1);
        }
      })(tail,head);
    })(tail,head);
  }
  return JSON.stringify(arr)+": "+JSON.stringify(ret);
}

console.log(worm([2, 4, 45, 6, 19], 51));
console.log(worm([1, 11, 100, 1, 200, 3, 2, 1, 280], 280));
console.log(worm([1, 3, 6, 11, 1, 5, 4], 4));
console.log(worm([2, 4, 45, 6, 0, 19], 51));
console.log(worm([2, 4, 0, 45, 0, 6, 0, 19], 51));
console.log(worm([0, 2, 4, 0, 45, 0, 6, 0, 19], 51));
console.log(worm([0, 2, 4, 0, 45, 0, 6, 0, 19, 26], 51));
console.log(worm([0, 2, 4, 0, 45, 0, 6, 0, 19, 26, 0], 51));
console.log(worm([1,8,2], 10));
console.log(worm([0,1,0,8,2,0], 10));
console.log(worm([0,8,2,8,0], 10));
console.log(worm([0,8,0,2,0,8,0], 10));
```

I think it works (for non-negative elements), but the first one was simpler for sure.

Answer (score 0):

With map and filter

```js
const arr = [2, 4, 45, 6, 0, 19]
let t = 0

const result = arr.map((v,i)=>{
  return [v, t += v]
}).filter((v,i)=>v[1]<=51)

console.log(result)
```