# How to convert function in recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

I have the Problem: Given an unsorted array A of size N of non-negative integers, find a continuous sub-array which adds to a given number S.

following code is a generic way of solving the problem

```
for(let i=0;i<intArr.length;i++)
{
    sum = intArr[i];
    for(j=i+1;j<intArr.length;j++)
    {
        sum =sum+intArr[j];
        if(sum === S)
        {
            outArr.push({i,j});
            sum=0;break;
        }
    }
}
```

How this can be optimized in javascript?

Comment: The general optimization for this is to realize that when you extend a sub-array you just add the new element to the sum, and when you move the start to the right you subtract the old element from the sum.

Comment: So you don't have to keep starting the sums from scratch.

Comment: There are other optimizations that take advantage of the fact that the numbers are  non-negative, so the sum always increases as you extend the sub-array.

Comment: start to the right you subtract the old element from the sum - Does it mean the first number which was added in the sum? or all element so if my array is [2,3,4,5,7,8,1] S=12 the outputarr with above is [ { i: 0, j: 2 }, { i: 2, j: 3 }, { i: 5, j: 6 } ] how would you record the array index?

Comment: I am not so sure that the other topic is really a duplicate of this one, but posted an answer there about the strictly-positive (which is neat) and non-negative (which is a bit hairy) cases, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56445564/7916438